# Tracking grant violations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, audit

We are changing one of our application user logins from being `dbowner` to a more granular permission scheme--finally.

Is there a way from within SQL Server 2016 that I can track permission violations? That is, this new user cannot SELECT from table dbo.*TableName* so that I can review it and determine if it is appropriate or not.

I know I can trap errors from the program side of things and log them, but I would rather not rely on that if the database can log that for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-2017)™ to accomplish this. The `error_reported` event allows you to log a row to a file every time a certain error occurs. You can add additional information to what is logged such as `username` and `client_hostname`. Here is some example T-SQL to get you started that filters on only error code 262:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [error_262_to_file] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.nt_username,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([error_number]=(262)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\XE\error_262_to_file.xel')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

Suppose one of my most troublesome users logs in with his `sean_gallardy` login. I don't trust this user so I gave him very limited permissions. If he tries to view a query plan he gets the following error message in SSMS:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 4, Line 1
>
> SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'master'.

Here is what is logged to the extended event file in response:

[image]